# Is there any framework/tool that we can use to create Java Swing application as module based?

Tags: java, swing

We want to make our current Java Swing application as module based so that it can be loaded from configuration files.

Is there any framework/tool that helps in making our application as module based? I mean big components like JTextPane, JTable we can make as a module and load them wheneven required.

Comment: module I meant one or more Swing components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/) may help. The following article has details: [Spring: How to Create Decoupled Swing Components](http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-enabling-decoupled-swin)

You can also check out the [spring-richclient](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html) project.

Answer (score 1):

Modules is a design term. Create well designed application and call groups of classes "modules". You can pack your modules in separate jar file and then put them into classpath as your wish. This will give you some flexibility.

You can use injection framework like Spring or Guice. This allow you to decouple your components.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) along with [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

Google Guice will give you the ability to break up your application in modules.

I like using JGoodies as it is easy to use and doesn't have a big dependancy list.